# Fancy array indexing into different column indices of each row

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an `m`x`n` array. For each row, I have `s` (with `s` <= `n`) entries that I want to access. The number of entries `s` is the same for each row, but their indices vary. I'd like to index into `x` and extract this `m`x`s` subarray.

Here's a concrete example. Suppose I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

x = np.arange(4*5).reshape(-1,5)

Out[25]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

And here are the entries I want from each row:

```
col_ix = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[0,2,4],[3,4,2]])

Out[36]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [3, 4, 2]])
```

This array says that from row 0, I want entries 0, 1, and 2. From row 1, I want entries 1, 2, and 3. And so on. The result should be:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [18, 19, 17]])
```

I was able to obtain the above result by writing:

```
x[[[_] for _ in xrange(len(x))], col_ix]
```

which essentially does:

```
x[[[0],[1],[2],[3]], col_ix]
```

but I feel as though there is a better way. I should note that the end goal is to assign zero to each entry of this subarray.

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, can't you take advantage of broadcasting on the range?  Maybe something like

```
In [32]: x[np.arange(len(x))[:,None], col_ix]
Out[32]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [18, 19, 17]])
```

Comment: I hadn't realize you can use `None` to expand the dimension of an array in place.  Very useful!

Comment: It should really be `np.newaxis`, but that's just an alias for `None`; I`newaxis` is more useful to google, though. :-)

Comment: Wow! This is nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

As we need to access 3 columns on each row we need to repeat each row's index 3 times, we can do this using [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), now using the repeated row indices and flattened version of `col_ix` we can perform [multi-dimensional indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) on `x`:

```
>>> x[np.repeat(np.arange(a), col_ix.shape[1]), col_ix.ravel()].reshape(col_ix.shape)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [18, 19, 17]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with a way of selecting rows sequentially without first expanding the matrix, as in Ashwini's answer.  I thought of using:

```
x[:, col_ix].reshape([-1, col_ix.shape[1]])[0::x.shape[1], :]
```

This still generates an `x.shape` by `col_ix.shape[1]` intermediate.  It's OK so long as your actual arrays aren't too large.